# React.js key prop is not unique using uuid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get the unique ket prop error when mapping over array. I am using an unique id and I see the logs in the console.

```
// MaximumTemperature.js
const Data = (data) => [
    <td>{data.type}</td>,
     ...
]

const DataRow = (props) => {
    return (
        <tr>
            <Data {...props} />
        </tr>
    )
}

const DataBody = ({ model }) => {
    console.log(model.maximumTemperature())
    return (
        <tbody>
            {
                model.maximumTemperature().map(data => <DataRow key={data.id} {...data} />)
            }
        </tbody>
    )
}
```

I have added an auto increment id to each object using this method

```
data.forEach((o, i) => o.id = i + 1);
```

```
// google chrome data example
0:
id: 1997
place: "Aarhus"
...
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
id: 2001
place: "Copenhagen"
...
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

each object having an id still throws that error

Error

```
index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at Data (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:906:18)
    at tr
    at DataRow
    at tbody
    at DataBody (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:957:3)
    at table
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:18635:23
    at push../src/components/items/MaximumTemperature.js.__webpack_exports__.default (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:976:3)
    at div
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:13846:23
    at div
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:17957:23
    at div
```

Comment: You might be interested in [`crypto.randomUUID()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID).

Comment: *"I have tried to combine 2 uuids which should be more random..."* I don't think that's a valid assumption, but regardless, if you need to resort to something like that, it means your `uuid` function isn't creating UUIDs.

Comment: Side note: Assigning a new, random key each time you render a row is (at least) as bad as not having a key at all. Store the random ID in the data, and reuse it. Otherwise, there's no point in having it.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uuid()` will create a new id every time the component renders.

You should calculate and assign the ids to each element of the array before rendering so that they remain consistent across renders. Make sure that the ids are calculated only once throughout the component's lifecycle.

Following the above will make sure that the keys are stable but you should also make sure that they are unique.

If each element of the array has a property that is unique then use it as `key` instead of generating ids.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need i uuid as a key, with i from iterate it does the job:

```
// view.js
const DataBody = ({ model }) => (
    <tbody>
        {
            model.maximumTemperature().map((data,i)=> <DataRow key={i} {...data} />)
        }
    </tbody>
)
```

Comment: Using indexes for keys is [often an antipattern](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318). I think we can assume that if the OP is going to all this trouble, they know they can't use the index (for instance, because the rows change).

Comment: I have changed all DataRows like in your example. Everything works fine except the exact same DataRow that did not work previously